# Excel VBA - Copying dynamic range with certain values to new worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weekly data set divided among four values in column L. I'm trying to see if there is a script that can be run to move each value (and respective rows) to their own tab (i.e. all rows with value "X" in column J copied to sheet 2, all rows with value "Y" in column J copied to sheet 3). This is a dynamic data set so locking in specific rows to the script wouldn't work.

I tried running a super basic XLOOKUP, but it would only return the topmost row of data:

=XLOOKUP(">90 Days", 'Sheet1'!J:J, 'Sheet1'!A:L)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something quick and easy, you can use the FILTER function without having to use VBA.

In your case, on sheet 2, you could have the following:

```
=FILTER('Sheet1'!J:J, "X"='Sheet1'!L:L)
```

And similarly, on sheet 3:

```
=FILTER('Sheet1'!J:J, "Y"='Sheet1'!L:L)
```

This would result in a spillover function and can only be used in newer versions of Excel, so you would want to allow for indefinite spillover in whatever column you place the formula.

If you are set on using VBA as a solution, you could always load the entire used range into an array and process that row by row.

See here for a more thorough description of the FILTER function:
[Excel Vlookup Return All Matches](https://www.statology.org/excel-vlookup-return-all-matches/)